# why this is showing error

Tags: android

```
 public void addItemsOnSpinner1() {
                    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
                    List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
                    list.add("none,i am healthy");
                    list.add("Diabetes");
                    list.add("cancer");
                    list.add("HIV/AIDS");
                    list.add("Tuberculosis");
                    list.add("Coronary Artery");
                    list.add("respiratory disease");
                    ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
                    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                 };

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                           int pos, long id) {

                }
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // Another interface callback
                }
```

### error

```
1. Error:(93, 52) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(<anonymous OnClickListener>,int,List<String>)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,List) is not applicable

2. Error:(93, 52) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(<anonymous OnClickListener>,int,List<String>)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,List) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List) is not applicable
(actual argument <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,Object[]) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,Object[]) is not applicable
(actual argument <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(actual argument <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Comment: use  editText3.setText((age + 15)+""); just pass string value in setText("") method.

Comment: you are always putting age value by `editText3.setText(Integer.toString(age));` in else condition which will always showing 0. Try to initialize value in age like this `age = age - 10;`  and then setText age value in a editext.

Comment: thank you so much . it worked :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
 if (yes.isChecked()) {
    editText3.setText(age + 15); //<<<
  } else if (no.isChecked()) {
    editText3.setText(age - 10); //<<
  }
```

Passing `int` to `EditText.setText` method probably causing issue with `NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1` Exception.

Use `String.valueOf` for setting `int` as text in EditText.

And also remove following line:

```
editText3.setText(Integer.toString(age));
```

or move it inside `else-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`
instead of

```
button.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
editText3.setText(age+"", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

Comment: nice to hear this please accept this answer if its usefull to you @jenebarve

Answer (score 0):

Try to set text in  edittext in this way :

```
if (yes.isChecked()) {
age =age + 15
                    editText3.setText(Integer.toString(age));
                } else if (no.isChecked()) {
                   age =age - 10; 
                    editText3.setText(Integer.toString(age));

               }
```

Comment: Hello , kapil  please help me in developing this app ( i am beginner and this would help me to learn alot). In my app i have a text field name . now i want user to enter his name and then the output should come as "name of the user plus his age " for example "jhon your age is 63 "

Comment: @jenebarve you can `gettext` from `edittext` like this `String age = ageEditText.getText().toString();` likewise `gettext` of a entered name from user `String name = nameEditText.getText().toString();` and then get it like `String showText = name + " your age is " + age ; ` now you can show this string wherever you want .

Comment: thank you so much buddy . it worked . would you mind if i could add u on fb so that i could share images of my app with you and you would be able to provide me better guidance 

once again thanks a ton , friend

Comment: i am not able to find you on fb beacuse there are alot of kapil rajput :(

[link](https://www.facebook.com/jenebarve143)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this ,

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //your code of declaration    
            }
  });
```

AND

```
if (yes.isChecked()) {
        editText3.setText(""+(age + 15));
   } else if (no.isChecked()) {
        editText3.setText(""+(age - 10));


 editText3.setText(String.valueOf(age));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do initialization outside the `onClick` method:

```
 CheckBox yes = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yes);
 CheckBox no  = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.no);
 EditText ageText   = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageText);
 EditText editText  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
 EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

 button.setOnClickListener(
   new Button.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View view) {
       int age;
       age = 0 ;

     if (yes.isChecked()) {
     String age =String.valueof(age)+15;
     editText3.setText(age);
   } else if (no.isChecked()) {
     String age = String.valueof(age)-10;
     editText3.setText(age);
   }
     }    
   });
```

Comment: `editText3.setText(age + 15);` and `editText3.setText(age - 10);` lines will crash application with `NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1 ` message

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate your View's outside of click listener.

```
CheckBox yes = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yes);
                        CheckBox no = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.no);
                        EditText ageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageText);
                        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                        EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
```